# Java XML create

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to get an attribute id (`fileID`)  from my XML document to use as the filename for my XML split. The split works I just need to extract the `fileID` to use as the name.

[EDITED] I can read the attribute now but it doesn't create the last xml file. So in my example it create the  first 2 files with the correct name but last fileID "000154OP.XML" isn't created. Can Anyone Help?

This is my xml document

```
<root>
 <envelope fileID="000152OP.XML">
   <record id="850">
   </record>
</envelope>
<envelope fileID="000153OP.XML">
  <record id="850">
  </record>
</envelope>
<envelope fileID="000154OP.XML">
  <record id="850">
  </record>
</envelope>
</root>
```

And here's my Java code

```
    public static void splitXMLFile (String file) throws Exception {         
    String[] temp;
    String[] temp2;
    String[] temp3;
    String[] temp4;
    String[] temp5;
    String[] temp6;
    File input = new File(file);         
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();         
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();          
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//root/envelope", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);          
    int itemsPerFile = 1;         

    Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("envelope").item(0);

    NamedNodeMap attr = staff.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("fileID");
    String node = nodeAttr.toString();
    temp = node.split("=");
    temp2 = temp[1].split("^\"");
    temp3 = temp2[1].split("\\.");

    Document currentDoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();         
    Node rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("root");   
    File currentFile = new File("C:\\XMLFiles\\" + temp3[0]+ ".xml"); 

    for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {             
        Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true);             
        rootNode.appendChild(imported); 

        Node staff2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("envelope").item(i);
        NamedNodeMap attr2 = staff2.getAttributes();
        Node nodeAttr2 = attr2.getNamedItem("fileID");
        String node2 = nodeAttr2.toString();
        temp4 = node2.split("=");
        temp5 = temp4[1].split("^\"");
        temp6 = temp5[1].split("\\.");

        if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) { 

            writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);                  
            rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("root");    
            currentFile = new File("C:\\XMLFiles\\" + temp6[0]+".xml");


        }         
    }          
    writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);     
}    

 private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {         
     Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();         
     transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));     
 }
```

Comment: If all you want from this function is to get a list of `.xml` files, I think you should consider just extracting the `@fileID` attributes as part of the XPath query. It would remove a lot of the complexity in your current solution.

Comment: @andyb I don't want list but want to split the XML-file based on the attribute of the split files.

Comment: @Eve OK, so you need to create XML files as well. I'll compile the code myself :-)

Comment: You should look at your logic here aswell: if (i % itemsPerFile == 0)

Comment: @ZeroPage, What do you suggest I change it to? !! EDIT I removed the if-statement but it still gives the same problem.

Comment: @Eve I have compiled the code and can reproduce the problem. I should have a solution soon :-)

Comment: Eww! What are all those `String[]` temp variables doing there!

Comment: Also, you really should try not to ask the same or very similar questions. I see you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341203/java-xml-getattribute just before this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of duplication in your code but I have a solution that removes a lot of it. I know there are less complex solutions (for example I don't think the `if (i % itemsPerFile == 0)` logic is required, but I do not know all of your requirements, so I have left it in.

The main problems you have were overwriting the last file with wrong data but also that your looping logic was duplicated. A good rule of thumb I go by is whenever I think I might have to duplicate code there is something wrong. Your logic was considering the *first* `<envelope>` separately to the remaining `<envelope>` elements, whereas they *should* be considered as a group of 3. Then your logic need only to apply the same searching, splitting, matching, importing, etc… to each element in turn.

What complicated matters, is that your input `XML` file had the same `<record id="850">` for each `<envelope>`. I changed mine to `850`, `851` and `852`. Running your original code, produced 3 files, `000152OP.xml`, `000153OP.xml` and `000154OP.xml`, but the first one contained the `851` record. So I immediately knew the looping logic was incorrect.

A simpler solution is detailed below, which given your input XML file as the argument produces 3 output files in the same directory (I removed the `C:\` hard-coding for simplicity), each with the correct `<record>` element.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class SplitXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File(args[0]);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//root/envelope", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        int itemsPerFile = 1;

        Document currentDoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("root");

            Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i), true);
            rootNode.appendChild(imported);

            Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("envelope").item(i);
            NamedNodeMap attr = staff.getAttributes();
            Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("fileID");
            String filename = nodeAttr.getNodeValue();
            String[] fileParts = filename.split("\\.");

            if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) {
                File currentFile = new File(fileParts[0] + "." + fileParts[1].toLowerCase());
                writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));
    }
}
```

You should read up on [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) and [String::split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) as there was unnecessary extra code where a native method already exists (for example `[Node::getNodeValue()][3]`).

**Edit:** The source for creating 1000 `<envelope>` elements that I used to test the above code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CreateXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File("split.xml"));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write("<root>");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            out.write("<envelope fileID=\"000" + i +"P.XML\"><record id=\"" + i + "\"></record></envelope>\n");
        }
        out.write("</root>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I ran `java CreateXML` to create the input file `split.xml` and then `java SplitXML split.xml` to create the 1000 files.

Comment: the only thing i edited was the part of the file entry and removed the (i % itemsPerFile == 0) part but all i get is NULL

Comment: How are you executing the code. With your XML file as the first argument, I get 3 files created. Are you running the application this way?

Comment: I changed the args[0] into the filename it have with contains 1000 instead of 3 and then run

Comment: I have just run this exact code with an XML file containing 1000 `<envelope>` elements and it created 1000 XML files. There isn't any actual output on the console, it just creates files.

Comment: Ok i have it working, was looking in wrong directory it placed files in workspace. But what if i want to remove the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root> part?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {}
```

instead of

```
 for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {}
```

Comment: Also change Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true); to ... nodes.item(i)...

Comment: int i=0 doesn't work, it doesn't create the other files if i change this.

Comment: @Nick removing the boolean gives an error. because importNode requires this.

Comment: I added ellipsis before and after nodes.item(i) -- meaning that was only piece of code meant to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of writeToFile(Node node, File file). This will Close outputStream. without closing the outputStream , it is difficult to handle file operations like delete, move file operation.

```
private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file){
    Transformer transformer = null;
    StreamResult sr = null;
    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
         sr = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file,false));
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), sr);
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
        try {
            sr.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```